# Open Flash CSS5.5 file on CS5 or how to get the AS code

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

I don't know if this is the right place to post this but... I have a file, which I created on Flash CS5.5 on another computer (I can't have access to that computer anymore) but I forgot at home I have Flash CS5. And now that I want to open it I can't. I was wondering if there is any way to get the actionscript code from the SWF or FLA file. Using a decompiler will work? I'm using a Mac with Lion and I haven't found nothing.

Maybe if someone with Flash CS5.5 could help me. If I send someone the file to open it with CS5.5 and only giving me the ActionScript code or making it compatible with CS5 :(.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Send the CS5.5 file along, I can change it

Comment: Thanks for your help but I've already gotten the code! But is it possible to get the actionscript code from a Fla or Swf file?. Thanks again!

Comment: You could decompile. Sothink swf decompiler is a decent one, but you'll have to buy the full version to be able to get the AS code in the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I built a tool called Flannel for just this occasion:
http://ajarproductions.com/blog/2012/03/06/flannel-open-newer-fla-files/

Comment: I've solved the problem the day I got it. I'll give it a try and if it works I'll donate and make your answer the best one!.

Comment: I wish I had this before when I was in hurry... haha. It worked! This should be really helpful for a lot of people!. Thanks! And... Done! (what I said).

Comment: It was going to be more but I have a lot of debts! Sorry

Comment: No worries. Still much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could always get a trial version of CS5.5 from Adobe just to open the file and grab the AS.

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash

Comment: Thanks but I didn't have time to download all so I just downloaded a "portable" version (500MB) on a PC with Windows... I've gotten the code! I just thought there was another way...